# Raiders of the lost book

Tags: functional-analysis

I am a phD student who would like to consult the following book:

J. Bourgain: "La propriete de Radon-Nikodym." Publications de l'universite Pierre et Marie Curie.

According to what I have found out, I would have to pay 200 euros to get the book in my university during two weeks just for consulting. I find this really disgraceful... Does anyone know about some website where it is possible to consult scanned versions of out-of-print mathematical books?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Worldcat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/propriete-de-radon-nikodym-cours-de-3eme-cycle/oclc/15538446&referer=brief_results) lists five copies in the United States. That's the approach I'd usually take to finding a rare book. Then if you're associated with a university you may well be able to get an interlibrary loan to acquire the book at home.